# ¿Cómo realizar consultas SQL de Oracle en Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, oracle

He estado queriendo aprender a utilizar el framework `Laravel` para mis proyectos, y tenia la idea de usar `Oracle` como BD *(que es la BD que más utilizo, personalmente)* con dicho framework.

Lo primero que me encuentro son las "Relaciones" en `Laravel`:

- Uno a muchos
- Muchos a Uno
- Muchos a muchos

Pero me llego la duda de, ¿Como seria posible poder realizar consultas `SQL` con sintaxis de `Oracle` en un framework como `Laravel`?

Utilizando como ejemplo, la siguiente consulta (la cual he buscado en [internet](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)):

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e
       JOIN dept_count dc ON e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```